# How to add a random word from one array to another empty array and then show that word in a list format using the list element in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have an array with 5 words in it. Now, I have to add those words randomly from this array to a new empty array and then finally show them in a list format every time a button is clicked. This is the code I have right now:

```
struct NewWords: Identifiable {
    
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var word: String
    
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    var words:[String] = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
    
    var newList:[NewWords] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button("Click me") {
                makeNewList()
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            List(newList) { item in
                Text(item.word)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    func makeNewList() {
        let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0..<words.count)
        print(words[randomNumber])
        newList.append(words[randomNumber])
    }  
}
```

I am able to print the random word but not able to put it inside the `List`. I tried using `append`, but I guess I am doing it wrong because it is throwing an error:

> "No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'"

Comment: Array has a function `randomElement()` that you can use.

Comment: `words[randomNumber]` returns a `String`. You need to make a `NewWords` out of that `String`

Comment: Array also has `.shuffled()`. Is there a particular reason that you want to use the `NewWords` struct or did you make it because the compiler complained that you needed to conform to `Identifiable`?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error on the line

```
newList.append(words[randomNumber])
```

because `newList` is an array of `NewWords` and `words[randomNumber]` returns a `String`.

You can fix this by creating a `NewWords` from your random word:

```
newList.append(NewWords(word:words[randomNumber]))
```

However, I suspect that you have created `NewWords` because the compiler previously complained that "String does not conform to Identifiable" on your `List`.

To fix that you can explicitly supply an identifier key path to `List`. The key path `\.self` will work in this case.

You can also use the `.shuffled()` function on your array to make your code much simpler

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var words:[String] = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
    
    @State var newList:[String] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button("Click me") {
                self.newList = words.shuffled()
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            List(newList, id:\.self) { word in
                Text(word)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul for the quick reply and explanation. I am a beginner with swift so concepts like (.\self) and .shuffled() are a little new to me. But let me try researching them and understanding them. Should be fine only. Again thank you so much!

Comment: I am getting two errors when I paste the above code. 

1. On Self.newList = words.shuffled()

the error says "Instance member 'newList' cannot be used on type 'ContentView'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?"


2. newList, id: .\self

error says "Expected identifier after '.' expression"

Comment: Sorry, my phone capitalised `self` and I didn't notice and I accidentally mis-ordered the `\.`

Comment: yup, it works pretty nicely now Paul. Thank you so much!